# Pattern recognition. Could be very easy

Tags: pattern

What pattern is in the Puzzle below? What replaces the "?". You have 4 choices.

[image]

Hint

> Turn them into words

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer is:

> **Zn** - the chemical symbol for **Zinc**.

Why? First, let's write out the names of the shapes, the numbers represented by the Roman numerals, and the chemical elements from the diagram:

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ELLIPSE | SQUARE | RHOMBUS | STAR |
| ELEVEN | NINE | TEN | EIGHT |
| MANGANESE | RADIUM | COPPER | ? |

Now, note what happens if you...

> ...read the entries of each row from right to left:
>
>  STA**R**, **R**HOMBU**S**, **S**QUAR**E**, **E**LLIPSE
>  EIGH**T**, **T**E**N**, **N**IN**E**, **E**LEVEN
>  ?, **C**OPPE**R**, **R**ADIU**M**, **M**ANGANESE
>
>  We have a sequence where the last letter of one word matches the first letter of the next! To this end, we need to choose the chemical symbol representing an element ending in 'C' (to fit beside Copper). Given that our options are Oxygen (O), Zinc (Zn), Tin (Sn) and Zirconium (Zr), the only one of these which ends in C and satisfies the pattern is **ZINC**!

Comment: Did you get it before I added the hint?

Comment: @DrD I had already previously done what the hint suggested, but hadn't been able to spot the solution. The hint confirmed for me that I was on the right track and should keep looking at what I'd got until I extracted something that made logical sense  :)